# Why is this variable returning true when it's false?

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

I am making a program that gets the GCD from 2 numbers. A problem I am having is that for some numbers like 168 and 132, I get something that isn't divisible by either of them.

For example, when I use the code below I get 84 instead of 12.

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    minimun = min(a, b)
    maximum = max(a, b)

    for i in range(1, a + 1):
        check = minimun % 1 == 0 and maximum % i == 0
        if check == True:
            gcd = i

    return gcd

print(gcdIter(168, 132))
```

Comment: Anything modulus 1 will always be 0

Comment: I'm taking MITx 6.00.1x. We're only on week 2. Give me a break and don't be rude please.

Comment: @takendarkk frankly I don't see how a debugger would help there. Watching the code with another pair of eyes is the best way here. I personally NEVER use a debugger with python (but I use a ton of `print` statements)

Answer (score 3):

you have a typo. Minimum % i instead of 1

`check = minimun % 1 == 0 and maximum % i == 0`

Comment: Yep that was it. I'm so dumb.

Comment: @JordanBaron Rest assured. Trust me, I had way more stupid moments.

Comment: there's a typo in `minimun` variable name too :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre LOL nice catch

Comment: I guess OP fingers betrayed him at this very moment, which could explain the 1 too :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I had my finger betraying me when playing online chess. Thats WAYY worse